# Add picture background and text on hover Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change to make a picture change on hover. This is what I've done so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="picture">
          <div class="text">
              <h1>Hey everyone!</h1>
          </div>

      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.picture{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");}.text{
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
width:200px;
height: 200px;
display: none;}
```

**javascript**

```
$(".picture").hover(function(){
$(this).children(".text").fadeToggle();});
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about what you are trying to acheive because the text seems to be displaying on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### jQuery (change background / show text):

HTML:

```
<div class="picture">
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Hey everyone!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.picture {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
}

.text {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".picture").hover(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.7
    }, 100, function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/Bliss_%28Windows_XP%29.png')");
    });

    $(".text").fadeToggle();
}, function() {

    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.7
    }, 100, function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg')");
    });

    $(".text").fadeToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/28vschr1/

#### CSS only solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="picture">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Hey everyone!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.picture {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
}

.text {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.picture:hover {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/Bliss_%28Windows_XP%29.png");
}

.picture:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/9vnokdec/

Comment: how to make the pink color and the text appear from the top to the bottom?

Comment: @ElleWilliamssss - do you want to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/8umg4ch2/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine as you can see in this example :

```js
$(".picture").hover(function() {
  $(this).children(".text").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.picture {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
}

.text {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Hey everyone!</h1>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: IDK why it's not working on chrome when I try. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @ElleWilliamssss Can you check your console? Do you have any errors showing?

Comment: I suggest you post another question with your full code, because `ESLint` has nothing to do with what you're asking :-)

Comment: okay. also how to make the red color appear from the top to the bottom? can u help me with that?

Comment: @ElleWilliamssss you can't, please see [here](https://tutorialcodeplay.com/jquery/jquery-fadetoggle.html) to check the fadeToggle options.

Comment: is there any other method that can help me achieve what I'm intending?

Comment: What you're asking can be done with CSS alone, but it is out of scope of this question and would require some initial investigation on your part first. Check out CSS transitions/animations for more information